# Tableau programming

Tags: hadoop, open-source, apache-spark, tableau-api

I am new here, and i hope that i could find answers for my questions related to open source reporting systems.

- Is it possible to change in the programming logic of 'Tableau desktop'? I am asking this because i need to make changes that
  enables me to log users' interactions with the system (Tableau
  Desktop).
- Is it possible to perform Big Data analysis by combining Tableau Desktop with Hadoop or Spark?
- If the answers for the above questions is no, then could you please
  recommend any other open source (free) reporting system that satisfy
  these requirements.

Thank you in advance and best regards to all of you

Answer (score 1):

Tableau has drivers to connect to several "big data" No SQL databases, and has added a Spark SQL driver as of Tableau version 8.3.

The full list of supported drivers can be found on Tableau's website at http://www.tableau.com/support/drivers

Your question about logging user interactions is not at all clear, but you might have better luck instituting logging at the database level instead of at client level.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your question regarding user interactions, I'd recommend you take a look at the [views_stats](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/data_dictionary.html#_views_stats_anchor) table in the Tableau Server database.

Instructions for connecting to the 'workgroup' database: http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/adminview_postgres_connect.htm

Answer (score 0):

Versions 8 and 9 includes a Spark connection

As far as logging users goes, Tableau Desktop is designed as a single license tool for developers and shouldn't need to be logged.

If you're interested in logging users, you may be thinking of Tableau Server, which has built-in functions for things like that as well as a [REST API](http://www.tableau.com/learn/tutorials/on-demand/rest-api), which has some additional functions.